# VB script to monitor disk space of multiple servers

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a VBScript to execute on a daily basis using a scheduled task to read in a list of servers and obtain the following information:

1. Server Name
2. Total Capacity in GB
3. Used Capacity in GB
4. Free Space
5. Free Space as a %

I then want this information to populate an excel spreadsheet with the information.

I then want instead of writing over this information obtained I want to append the new data collected each day to the spreadsheet thus allowing a trend analysis to be achieved.

Can anyone help me with the above requirements?

```
strInputFile = "D:\Disk_Space\servers.txt"
strOutputFile = "D:\Disk_Space\disk_space_report.csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const intForReading = 1

Const adVarChar = 200
Const MaxCharacters = 255

Dim DataList
Set DataList = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
DataList.Fields.Append "Server", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "C Free Space", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "C Percent Free", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "D Free Space", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "D Percent Free", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "E Free Space", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "E Percent Free", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "F Free Space", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Fields.Append "F Percent Free", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
DataList.Open

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, intForReading)
While Not objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
strComputer = objInputFile.ReadLine
Get_Free_Space_Details(strComputer)
Wend

Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputFile, True)
objOutputFile.WriteLine """SERVER"",""C FREE SPACE"",""C PERCENT FREE"",""D FREE SPACE"",""D PERCENT FREE"",""E FREE SPACE"",""E PERCENT FREE"",""F FREE SPACE"",""F PERCENT FREE"""
DataList.MoveFirst
 While Not DataList.EOF
objOutputFile.WriteLine """" & DataList("Server") & """,""" & DataList("C Free Space") & """,""" & DataList("C Percent Free") & """,""" & DataList("D Free Space") & """,""" & DataList("D Percent Free") & """,""" & DataList("E Free Space") & """,""" & DataList("E Percent Free") & """,""" & DataList("F Free Space") & """,""" & DataList("F Percent Free") & """"
 DataList.MoveNext
 Wend
 DataList.Close
 objOutputFile.Close

 MsgBox "Done. Please see " & strOutputFile
 '==============

 Sub Get_Free_Space_Details(strComputer)

DataList.AddNew
DataList("Server") = strComputer
If Ping(strComputer) = True Then 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 3")
        For Each objDisk In colDisks
            strDrive = objDisk.DeviceID
            intFreeSpace = objDisk.FreeSpace
            intTotalSpace = objDisk.Size
            pctFreeSpace = intFreeSpace / intTotalSpace
            Select Case UCase(strDrive)
                Case "C:"
                    DataList("C Free Space") = Round(intFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GB"
                    DataList("C Percent Free") = FormatPercent(pctFreeSpace)
                Case "D:"
                    DataList("D Free Space") = Round(intFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GB"
                    DataList("D Percent Free") = FormatPercent(pctFreeSpace)
                Case "E:"
                    DataList("E Free Space") = Round(intFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GB"
                    DataList("E Percent Free") = FormatPercent(pctFreeSpace)
                Case "F:"
                    DataList("F Free Space") = Round(intFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GB"
                    DataList("F Percent Free") = FormatPercent(pctFreeSpace)
            End Select
        Next
        
        Set objDisk = Nothing
        Set colDisks = Nothing
        Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Else
        DataList("C Free Space") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("C Percent Free") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("D Free Space") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("D Percent Free") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("E Free Space") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("E Percent Free") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("F Free Space") = "WMI ERROR"
        DataList("F Percent Free") = "WMI ERROR"
    End If
Else
    DataList("C Free Space") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("C Percent Free") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("D Free Space") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("D Percent Free") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("E Free Space") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("E Percent Free") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("F Free Space") = "OFFLINE"
    DataList("F Percent Free") = "OFFLINE"
End If
DataList.Update
End Sub

Function Ping(strComputer)
Dim objShell, boolCode
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
boolCode = objShell.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 300 " & strComputer, 0, True)
If boolCode = 0 Then
    Ping = True
Else
    Ping = False
End If
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
' Check drive c free space
'
On Error Resume Next

Const MIN_FREE = 38.2 ' Gb
Const ForAppending = 8
Const HARD_DISK = 3
Const ForReading = 1
CONST ForWriting = 2 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SrvList = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\servers.txt", ForReading)
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ReportFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\disk_space_report.csv", ForAppending, True)
strComputer = "."


ReportFile.writeline "Computer" & vbTAB & "Drive C Free (Gb)" & vbTAB & "Status" & vbTAB & "Drive D Free (Gb)"



Do Until SrvList.AtEndOfStream

StrComputer = SrvList.Readline
'wscript.echo now & vbTAB & StrComputer

If Not IsConnectible(strComputer, "", "") Then

ReportFile.writeline(strComputer & vbTAB & " no available")

Else

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = " & HARD_DISK & " AND DeviceID = 'C:' ") 

Set colDisks1 = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = " & HARD_DISK & " AND DeviceID = 'D:' ") 

For Each objDisk in colDisks 
    FreeGB = objDisk.FreeSpace / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
    Size = objDisk.Size  / 1073741824
    UsedSpace = (objDisk.Size-objDisk.FreeSpace) / 1073741824
    FreeGBPercent = FormatPercent(objDisk.FreeSpace/objDisk.Size)
    strStatus = "ok"      
    If FreeGB < MIN_FREE Then strStatus = "Low disk"
    ReportFile.writeline(strComputer & vbTAB & Round(FreeGB,2) & vbTAB & strStatus & vbTAB & Round(Size,2) & vbTAB & Round(UsedSpace,2) & vbTAB & FreeGBPercent)
Next 

For Each objDisk in colDisks1 
    FreeGB = objDisk.FreeSpace / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
    Size = objDisk.Size  / 1073741824
    UsedSpace = (objDisk.Size-objDisk.FreeSpace) / 1073741824
    FreeGBPercent = FormatPercent(objDisk.FreeSpace/objDisk.Size)
    strStatus = "ok"      
    If FreeGB < MIN_FREE Then strStatus = "Low disk"
    ReportFile.writeline(strComputer & vbTAB & Round(FreeGB,2) & vbTAB & strStatus & vbTAB & Round(Size,2) & vbTAB & Round(UsedSpace,2) & vbTAB & FreeGBPercent)
Next 
End If    

Loop


'
Wscript.Quit 

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)

WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & _
     Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) _
     & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & _
     Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, _
     13, 2))

End Function


Function IsConnectible(sHost, iPings, iTO) 



Const OpenAsASCII      =  0 
Const FailIfNotExist  =  0 
Const ForReading      =  1 
Dim sTempFile, fFile

If iPings = "" Then iPings = 2 
If iTO = "" Then iTO = 750 


 sTempFile = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2).ShortPath & "\" & objFSO.GetTempName

 oShell.Run "%comspec% /c ping.exe -n " & iPings & " -w " & iTO & " " & sHost & ">" & sTempFile, 0 , True 
 Set fFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sTempFile, ForReading, FailIfNotExist, OpenAsASCII) 

  Select Case InStr(fFile.ReadAll, "TTL=")
  Case 0 IsConnectible = False 
  Case Else IsConnectible = True 
  End Select 

  fFile.Close
  objFSO.DeleteFile(sTempFile) 

  End Function
```

Tested with 127.0.0.1 in servers.txt

Output is:

```
"Computer   Drive C Free (Gb)   Status  Drive D Free (Gb)"
"127.0.0.1  67.72   ok  237.87  170.15  28.47%"
"127.0.0.1  102.16  ok  443.21  341.06  23.05%"
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated my answer and this code works absolutely fine for me except that it prompt me with a msgBox - MsgBox "Done. Please see " & strOutputFile adn until i press ok it doesn't append the data in output file. Can you help me with the same.

Comment: If you delete line 39  MsgBox "Done. Please see " & strOutputFile it doesn't work?

Comment: hey ALex, that worked.. but when I am running the vbs script through batch file it gives me the message "Press any key to continue..." and until I presses OK it doesn't append the data in the output file.

Comment: That is a different issue. Check your batch file for echos or pauses.